# Get executed SQL by GORM without DryRun Mode

Tags: go, go-gorm

Is it possible to get SQL run by Gorm without using DryRun?
I would like to run the SQL, and if this SQL error I would like to record it in a LOG along with several other information. Is there any way I can retrieve this executed SQL?

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to achieve getting SQL in the log

If you only want to output SQL for specific query, then using `db.Debug()` will change the log level for that query to `INFO`.

```
db.Debug().Where("name = ?", "jinzhu").First(&User{})
```

If you want to output SQL globally for your application, configure the logger when initialize the `gorm.DB` instance

```
newLogger := logger.New(
    log.New(os.Stdout, "\r\n", log.LstdFlags),
    logger.Config{
        LogLevel:                   logger.Info, // Log level Info will output everything
    },
)

// Globally mode
db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("test.db"), &gorm.Config{
    Logger: newLogger,
})
```

Details at [gorm logger](https://gorm.io/docs/logger.html).

Comment: Is there no other way to do this without creating a CustomLogger? There is no function called .SQL() or something similar?

Comment: In GORM V1 I fork the project and also made a pull request to add this functionality: https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/pull/16. I thought that in GORM V2 this was already developed.

Comment: In gorm V1, you can use db.LogMode(true) to enable. But they removed it in V2, so the only way is to use custom logger.

Comment: But LogMode only prints the SQL in the terminal. I would like to have the SQL string.